# How to fetch a date parameter from the SQL Task and pass it on to Data Flow tasks

Tags: ssis-2012

I need to fetch a parameter from "Execute SQL Task" and pass it on to 10 different Data Flow tasks, 
so that all these 10 DF uses the same parameter which is been generated by Execute SQL task flow.
So far what i have done is this;

1. I have the SQL Task editor and used the connections type as `ODBC, SQLSourceType=Direct Input & SQL Statement = select max(date) from table where package = 'PackageName';`
2. This SQL Task gets connected to 10 different Data Flows.

Comment: From the SQL Task, is the date put into a variable? How does the SQL task "get conmected" ro the other data flow tasks?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is execute the sql script and return the value (the date) into a variable. Then have that variable available to the data flow tasks so they all have the same value.

Assuming this is the case, you need to first declare a variable in the package to hold the date returned from the query. Make sure the scope is available to the entire package.

Next, in order to setup your sql task correctly, you need to map the results of the sql script to the variable. In the SQL Task Editor, in the General Tab, set the result set to Single Row.  Next, add a variable under the Result Set tab to receive the date from the query.  For Result name, that will be the column returned from the query that is executed (you should give a name to column that returns max date).  The variable name is where you put the variable you declared in the package.  Now, when you execute the package the value from the query is stored in variable and is available to be used wherever you want.

I can't comment that much about how to apply that variable in the dataflow tasks without knowing which type of tasks you will use it in.  But from this point, you can use the variable just like any other static variable that you would create.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Jason. Much appreciated.